# Is K-means for clustering data with many zero values?

Tags: matrix, cluster-analysis, k-means

I need to cluster a matrix which contains mostly zeros values...Is K-means appropriate for these kind of data or do I need to consider a different algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

No. The reason is that the **mean** is not sensible on sparse data. The resulting mean vectors will have very different characteristics than your actual data; they will often end up being more similar to each other than to actual documents!

There are some modifications that improve k-means for sparse data such as *spherical* k-means.

But largely, k-means on such data is just a crude heuristic. The results aren't entirely useless, but they are not the best that you can do either. It works, but by chance, not by design.

Answer (score 1):

*k*-means is widely used to cluster sparse data such as document-term vectors, so I'd say go ahead. Whether you get good results depends on the data and what you're looking for, of course.

There are a few things to keep in mind:

- If you have very sparse data, then a [sparse representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) of your input can reduce memory usage and runtime by many orders of magnitude, so pick a good *k*-means implementation.
- Euclidean distance isn't always the best metric for sparse vectors, but normalizing them to unit length may give better results.
- The cluster centroids are in all likelihood going to be dense regardless of the input sparsity, so don't use too many features.
- Doing dimensionality reduction, e.g. SVD, on the samples may boost the running time and cluster quality a lot.